# Spark ML, parameter for "rawPredictionCol" for Binary Classification

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I want to use The binary Classificator in Spark.ml to evaluate my model after my Pipeline. I use this code :

```
val gbt = new GBTClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("Label_Index")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setMaxDepth(7)
  .setSubsamplingRate(0.1)
  .setMinInstancesPerNode(15)


// Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
  val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol("prediction")
  .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
  .setLabels(indexer_2.labels)

val evaluator_auc = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
.setLabelCol("Label_Index")
.setRawPredictionCol("")
.setMetricName("areaUnderROC")
```

I don't know really which parameters I need to give to "setRawPredictionCol()", I think I need to give the result of my prediction, the column "prediction"

Comment: looks like it should be predictedLabel?

Comment: @ryanmc, I get this error : "Column predictedLabel must be of type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce but was actually StringType." So I need to give a Vector with the column "predicition" which is a the result of the prediction as integer. I don't know how to convert an interger to a Vector type...

Comment: Ah I see - looks like gradient boosted trees do not have probabilities outputted in order to construct the ROC curve - hopefully you can get away with using random forest for now

Comment: @ryanmc, yes it is exactly what you sayed, Gradient Boosting do not return "rawPredictionCol" to reconstruct ROC curve. So I will use Random Forest. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to get raw probabilities from the LogisticRegression ML classifier. I'm trying to use it with OneVsRest in ML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903288/what-do-columns-rawprediction-and-probability-of-dataframe-mean-in-spark-mll#:~:text=rawPrediction%20is%20the%20raw%20output,equal%20to%20that%20of%20rawPrediction%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903288/what-do-columns-rawprediction-and-probability-of-dataframe-mean-in-spark-mll#:%7E:text=rawPrediction%20is%20the%20raw%20output,equal%20to%20that%20of%20rawPrediction%20)

For me, I use lightgbm of microsoft, the AUC of "rawPrediction" and "probability" differs smaller than 1e-15 on a binary dataset.