# What do columns ‘rawPrediction’ and ‘probability’ of DataFrame mean in Spark MLlib？

Tags: apache-spark-sql, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

After I trained a LogisticRegressionModel, I transformed the test data DF with it and get the prediction DF. And then when I call prediction.show(), the output column names are: `[label | features | rawPrediction | probability | prediction]`. I know what `label` and `featrues` mean, but how should I understand `rawPrediction|probability|prediction`?

Answer (score 18):

Note: please also see the answer below by desertnaut  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947815/1056563

`RawPrediction` is typically the direct probability/confidence calculation. From Spark docs:

> Raw prediction for each possible label. The meaning of a "raw"
>   prediction may vary between algorithms, but it intuitively gives a
>   measure of confidence in each possible label (where larger = more
>   confident).

The `Prediction` is the result of finding the statistical `mode` of the `rawPrediction - via`argmax`:

```
  protected def raw2prediction(rawPrediction: Vector): Double =
          rawPrediction.argmax
```

The `Probability` is the `conditional probability` for each class. Here is the `scaladoc`:

> Estimate the probability of each class given the raw prediction,
>   doing the computation in-place.    These predictions are also called
>   class conditional probabilities.

The actual calculation depends on which `Classifier` you are using.

**`DecisionTree`**

> Normalize a vector of raw predictions to be a
>   multinomial probability vector, in place.

It simply sums by class across the instances and then divides by the total instance count.

```
 class_k probability = Count_k/Count_Total
```

**`LogisticRegression`**

It uses the logistic formula

```
 class_k probability: 1/(1 + exp(-rawPrediction_k))
```

**`Naive Bayes`**

```
 class_k probability = exp(max(rawPrediction) - rawPrediction_k)
```

**`Random Forest`**

```
 class_k probability = Count_k/Count_Total
```

Comment: Thans  for your detailed explanation, but I still have some questions:  why probability is needed after rawPrediction has been calculated since they all indicate the “probability” of  each possible class   and   metric areaUnderROC and areaUnderPR in BinaryClassificationEvaluator are both calculated based  on rawPrediction?

Comment: @StarLee  The details on how the `Prediction` and `Probability` differ (are derived from ) the `rawPrediction` are shown in my answer - and taken directly from the source code. So I've answered this. Which part do you want more details about?

Comment: Some reference link would be appreciated - thanks (+1)

Comment: @desertnaut  I spelunked the codebase for the above information.

Comment: @desertnaut Is it available for Xgboost Classifier also? P.S [sparkdl.xgboost.XgboostClassifier]

Answer (score 12):

In older versions of the Spark [javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/ClassificationModel.html#predictRaw(FeaturesType)) (e.g. 1.5.x), there used to be the following explanation:

> The meaning of a "raw" prediction may vary between algorithms, but it intuitively gives a measure of confidence in each possible label (where larger = more confident).

It is not there in the later versions, but you can still find it in the Scala [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/Classifier.scala#L256).

Anyway, and any unfortunate wording aside, the `rawPrecictions` in Spark ML, for the logistic regression case, is what the rest of the world call [*logits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), i.e. the raw output of a logistic regression classifier, which is subsequently transformed into a probability score using the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) `exp(x)/(1+exp(x))`.

Here is an example with toy data in Pyspark:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
     (0.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.0)),
     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0))], 
     ["label", "features"])
df.show()
# +-----+---------+
# |label| features|
# +-----+---------+
# |  0.0|[0.0,1.0]|
# |  1.0|[1.0,0.0]|
# +-----+---------+

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, labelCol="label")
lr_model = lr.fit(df)

test = sc.parallelize([Row(features=Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.5)),
                       Row(features=Vectors.dense(0.5, 0.2))]).toDF()
lr_result = lr_model.transform(test)
lr_result.show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the result:

```python
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+ 
|features |                          rawPrediction |                            probability |prediction|
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+ 
|[0.2,0.5]|[0.9894187891647654,-0.9894187891647654]|[0.7289731070426124,0.27102689295738763]|      0.0 |
|[0.5,0.2]|[-0.9894187891647683,0.9894187891647683]|[0.2710268929573871,0.728973107042613]  |      1.0 | 
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

Let's now confirm that the logistic function of `rawPrediction` gives the `probability` column:

```python
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([0.9894187891647654,-0.9894187891647654])
np.exp(x1)/(1+np.exp(x1))
# array([ 0.72897311, 0.27102689])

x2 = np.array([-0.9894187891647683,0.9894187891647683])
np.exp(x2)/(1+np.exp(x2))
# array([ 0.27102689, 0.72897311])
```

i.e. this is the case indeed

---

So, to summarize regarding all three (3) output columns:

- `rawPrediction` is the raw output of the logistic regression classifier (array with length equal to the number of classes)
- `probability` is the result of applying the logistic function to `rawPrediction` (array of length equal to that of `rawPrediction`)
- `prediction` is the argument where the array `probability` takes its maximum value, and it gives the most probable label (single number)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine because of the actual code/examples

Comment: yes i had seen that thx. I put the comment here for benefit of other readers and also a comment at top of my answer referencing this one

Answer (score -1):

If classification model is logistic regression,

**rawPrediction** is equal (w*x + bias) variable coefficients values

**probability** is 1/(1+e^(w*x + bias))

**prediction** is 0 or 1.