# How to calculate Binary Classification Metrics in Spark MLlib with Dataframe API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I am using Spark MLlib with DataFrame API, given the following sample code:

```
val dtc = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
val testResults = dtc.fit(training).transform(test)
```

Can I calculate the model quality metrics over the `testResult` using the DataFrame API?

If not, how do I correctly transform my `testResult` (containing "label", "features", "rawPrediction", "probability", "prediction") so that I can use the `BinaryClassificationMetrics` (RDD API)?

NOTE: I am interested in the "byThreshold" metrics as well

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the constructor of the [BinaryClassificationMetrics](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala#L54), it takes an RDD[(Double, Double)], score and labels. You can convert the Dataframe to the right format like this:

```
val scoreAndLabels = testResults.select("label", "probability")
    .rdd
    .map(row => 
            (row.getAs[Vector]("probability")(1), row.getAs[Double]("label"))
    )
```

EDIT:

[Probability](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#decision-trees) is stored in a `Vector` that is the same length as the number of classes you'd like to predict. In the case of binary classification the first one would correspond to label = 0 and the second is label = 1, you should pick the column that is your positive label (normally label = 1).

Comment: I was thinking something like that. However, `"probability"` is a 2 elements Vector and I'm not sure which one to pick. If you take a look at how [BinaryClassificationEvaluator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/BinaryClassificationEvaluator.scala#L74) works, it takes the `rawPrediction` at index 1 and that confuses me for 2 reasons: Why using `rawPrediction` instead of `probability`? and why taking always index 1? I am tempted to use `"probability(1)"` for the `BinaryClassificationMetrics` object.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why "... pick the column that is your positive label"? I am confused about why BinaryClassificationEvaluator  always pick index 1 independently on what prediction has been geenerated

Comment: BinaryClassificationEvaluator makes the assumption that label = 0 is the negative label and label = 1 is the positive one. In some ML libraries, (ie scikit-learn), you have an option to pick which column is your positive/negative label (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html), looks like in `mllib` it is hardcoded.

Comment: If you always take probability(1) then the prediction is more likely to be correct for values very close to 1 and very close to 0 (where we are predictive negative with high probability). Is that the expected outcome?

Comment: yes, probability(1) represents P(label = 1), where high probability would more likely to be label 1 and low probability is label 0. If you take probability(0), then high probability is more likely to be label 0 and low probability is more likely to be label 1 (as probability(0) + probability(1) = 1).

Comment: Just for completeness of the discussion: Any reasons why I should prefer "probability" over "rawPrediction" (as shown in BinaryClassificationEvaluator)? IMO they are equivalent although with rawPrediction I cannot tell what's being predicted by my model by looking at one value of the Vector only.

Comment: Probabilities are easier to work with, as their range is between 0 and 1, which might not be the case for raw predictions of certain models, using probabilities BinaryClassificationEvaluator can be generalised. A few examples here how they differ for some models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903288/what-do-colum-rawprediction-and-probability-of-dataframe-mean-in-spark-mllib